# Memory leak issue during xml parsing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, memory-leaks

I got strange problem of memory leaks,

Now my code is,

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)getParsedWallpaperData{
NSMutableDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Wallpaper" ofType:@"xml"]];
TBXML *tbXml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLData:xmlData error:nil];

//TBXML *tbXml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithXMLData:xmlData error:nil] autorelease];

@synchronized(self){
    TBXMLElement *rootXMLElement = tbXml.rootXMLElement;

    if(rootXMLElement)
    {
        TBXMLElement *paging = [TBXML childElementNamed:kPaging parentElement:rootXMLElement];
        NSMutableDictionary *pagingData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        if(paging){
            TBXMLElement *totalPages = [TBXML childElementNamed:kTotalPages parentElement:paging];
            NSString *totalPagesString = [TBXML textForElement:totalPages];
            [pagingData setObject:totalPagesString forKey:@"TotalPages"];

            TBXMLElement *currentPage = [TBXML childElementNamed:kCurrentPage parentElement:paging];
            NSString *currentPageString = [TBXML textForElement:currentPage];
            [pagingData setObject:currentPageString forKey:@"CurrentPage"];

            TBXMLElement *prevPage = [TBXML childElementNamed:kPerviousPage parentElement:paging];
            NSString *prevPageString = [TBXML textForElement:prevPage];
            [pagingData setObject:prevPageString forKey:@"PreviousPage"];

            TBXMLElement *nextPage = [TBXML childElementNamed:kNextPage parentElement:paging];
            NSString *nextPageString = [TBXML textForElement:nextPage];
            [pagingData setObject:nextPageString forKey:@"NextPage"];
        }
        [dataDictionary setObject:pagingData forKey:@"PagingInfo"];
        [pagingData release];
        pagingData = nil;

        TBXMLElement *totalItems = [TBXML childElementNamed:kTotalItems parentElement:rootXMLElement];
        NSString *totalItemsString = [TBXML textForElement:totalItems];
        [dataDictionary setObject:totalItemsString forKey:@"TotalItems"];

        NSMutableArray *itemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[totalItemsString intValue]]; 

        TBXMLElement *items = [TBXML childElementNamed:kItems parentElement:rootXMLElement];
        if(items){
            TBXMLElement *item = [TBXML childElementNamed:kItem parentElement:items];
            while (item) {
                NSMutableDictionary *itemInfoDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                TBXMLElement *title = [TBXML childElementNamed:kTitle parentElement:item];
                NSString *titleString = [TBXML textForElement:title];
                [itemInfoDict setObject:titleString forKey:@"Title"];

                TBXMLElement *image1 = [TBXML childElementNamed:kImage1 parentElement:item];
                NSString *image1String = [TBXML textForElement:image1];
                [itemInfoDict setObject:image1String forKey:@"Image1"];

                TBXMLElement *image2 = [TBXML childElementNamed:kImage2 parentElement:item];
                NSString *image2String = [TBXML textForElement:image2];
                [itemInfoDict setObject:image2String forKey:@"Image2"];

                TBXMLElement *image3 = [TBXML childElementNamed:kImage3 parentElement:item];
                NSString *image3String = [TBXML textForElement:image3];
                [itemInfoDict setObject:image3String forKey:@"Image3"];

                TBXMLElement *thumbnail = [TBXML childElementNamed:kThumbnail parentElement:item];
                NSString *thumbnailString = [TBXML textForElement:thumbnail];
                [itemInfoDict setObject:thumbnailString forKey:@"Thumbnail"];

                [itemArray addObject:itemInfoDict];
                [itemInfoDict release];
                itemInfoDict = nil;
                item = item -> nextSibling;
            }
        }
        [dataDictionary setObject:itemArray forKey:@"ImagesInfo"];
        [itemArray release];
        itemArray = nil;
    }
}

[tbXml release];
tbXml = nil; 
return dataDictionary;
 }
```

I found memory leak only  TBXML *tbXml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLData:xmlData error:nil]; on this line, even though i manually release  **tbXml** object,

Please suggest me y this happening?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked to see if it is a leak with in the TBXML library?

Comment: @freespace, i think there may be leak in TBXML library, becoz when i debug my code using analyzer it didn't gave me any issue in my given code .... but it shows many issues in TBXML library... :(

Comment: Then either (a) submit a bug report to TBXML or (b) stop using TBXML or (c) stop using XML. I recommend option (c).

Comment: I agree with @freespace's option c. If you have the file in your bundle as XML then replacing it with a json file will make it smaller and easier to work with.

Comment: @freespace also missed option a1) fix the errors that are shown in TBXML.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it's the root element there that is shown as leaking, I'm wondering if one of the accessors like `childElementNamed` is causing it (by returning something that acts like a NSString but really also has optimized pointers stored back to the root element). Can you look at the implementation of `childElementNamed`? A relatively quick way to alter your code to ensure it's not that would be to wrap any NSString result you were about to store in your `dataDictionary` there with a `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [TBXML textForElement:fooTitle]]` call.

Also, you could wrap this function in a `@nsautoreleasepool` macro, if TBXML is creating a lot of autoreleased objects.

As a final suggestion, you should look at ARC if you can (i.e., if you are deploying to iOS 4+).

Comment: i start code to write in ARC environment actually but my client changed requirement he said i want to give facility to user paly cocos2d game in the application. And that game code is not compatible with ARC therefore i choose non-ARC application... :(

Comment: i got 100% leak in instrument on TBXML *tbXml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLData:xmlData error:nil];
this line.

Comment: Yes - but that does not mean that the problem is in TBXML. Something is referencing the memory that was allocated on that line; so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: i don't think so, leaks comes from somewhere else becoz, if leaks come from somewhere else then i got the reference counter of that object in Instrument....but its not happening.... also analyzer gave that line where leaks generate.... when i start analyze my code using analyzer... it does not showing any problem in my code... but yes it gave many defects in TBXML library.

Comment: We may have to agree to disagree then. There may well be leaks in TBXML, but specifically you're not getting that the memory for this TBXML object is being retained. It cannot be leaked inside itself. Go to the alloc/release chain. The holder of that object (which is leaked) is probably not being identified as a leak itself because it is not a leak; it is validly referenced.

Comment: ,, yes may be you are right....on "probably not being identified as a leak itself because it is not a leak; it is validly referenced", i got also something strange result... if there is simultaneous memory leaks then there should be a extra memory allocation....but in my case memory is maintained not extra allocation...

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the top of your function:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *Pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
```

and add this line at the bottom of your function before "return" statement :

```
[Pool drain];
```

May this will help you out.

Comment: Replace the [Pool drain]; to [Pool release]; line.

Comment: Actually, your xmlData takes much of your application memory may it has much data in MBs. To solve the issue try to alloc the xmlData and release that object as soon you complete it to fed up in TBxml.